# How to execute a specific php script method giving parameters from url

Tags: php

I have this php script:

```
<?php

class Curl_Class {
    private $endpointUrl;
    private $userName;
    private $userKey;
    public $token;
    public $errorMsg = '';

    private $defaults = array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Expect:'),
            // CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
        );

    //constructor saves the values
    function __construct($url, $name, $key) {
        $this->endpointUrl=$url;
        $this->userName=$name;
        $this->userKey=$key;
        $this->token=$key;
    }

    private function getChallenge() {
        $curl_handler = curl_init();
        $params = array("operation" => "getchallenge", "username" => $this->userName);
        $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $this->endpointUrl."?".http_build_query($params));
        curl_setopt_array($curl_handler, ($this->defaults + $options));

        $result = curl_exec($curl_handler);
        if (!$result) {
            $this->errorMsg = curl_error($curl_handler);
            return false;
        }
        $jsonResponse = json_decode($result, true);

        if($jsonResponse["success"]==false) {
            $this->errorMsg = "getChallenge failed: ".$jsonResponse["error"]["message"]."<br>";
            return false;
        }

        $challengeToken = $jsonResponse["result"]["token"];

        return $challengeToken;
    }

    function login() {
        $curl_handler = curl_init();
        $token = $this->getChallenge();
        //create md5 string containing user access key from my preference menu
        //and the challenge token obtained from get challenge result
        $generatedKey = md5($token.$this->userKey);

        $params = array("operation" => "login", "username" => $this->userName, "accessKey" => $generatedKey);
        $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $this->endpointUrl, CURLOPT_POST => 1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params));
        curl_setopt_array($curl_handler, ($this->defaults + $options));
        $result = curl_exec($curl_handler);
        if (!$result) {
            $this->errorMsg = curl_error($curl_handler);
            return false;
        }
        $jsonResponse = json_decode($result, true);
        if($jsonResponse["success"]==false) {
            $this->errorMsg = "Login failed: ".$jsonResponse["error"]["message"]."<br>";
            return false;
        }

        $sessionId = $jsonResponse["result"]["sessionName"];
        //save session id
        $this->token=$sessionId;

        return true;
    }

    private function handleReturn($result, $name, $curl_handler) {
        if (!$result) {
            $this->errorMsg = curl_error($curl_handler);
            return false;
        }
        $jsonResponse = json_decode($result, true);

        if (!$jsonResponse) {
            $this->errorMsg = "$name failed: ".$result."<br>";
            return false;
        }
        if($jsonResponse["success"]==false) {
            $this->errorMsg = "$name failed: ".$jsonResponse["error"]["message"]."<br>";
            return false;
        }
        return $jsonResponse["result"];
    }

    public function operation($name, $params, $type = "GET", $filepath = '') {
        $params = array_merge(array("operation" => $name, "sessionName" => $this->token), $params);
        if (strtolower($type) == "post") {
            $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $this->endpointUrl, CURLOPT_POST => 1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params));
        }
        else {
            $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $this->endpointUrl."?".http_build_query($params));
        }

        if ($filepath != '' && strtolower($type) == "post") {
            $element = $params['element'];
            if (!empty($element)) {
                $element = json_decode($element, true);
            }
            if (isset($element['filename'])) {
                $filename = $element['filename'];
            }
            else {
                $filename = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            }
            $size = filesize($filepath);
            $add_options = array(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"), CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $size);
            if (function_exists("mime_content_type")) {
                $type = mime_content_type($filepath);
            }
            elseif (isset($element['filetype'])) {
                $type = $element['filetype'];
            }
            else {
                $type = '';
            }
            if (!function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
                $add_params = array("filename" => "@$filepath;type=$type;filename=$filename");
            }
            else {
                $cfile = curl_file_create($filepath, $type, $filename);
                $add_params = array('filename' => $cfile);
            }

            $options += $add_options;
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params + $add_params;
        }


        $curl_handler = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl_handler, ($this->defaults + $options));

        $result = curl_exec($curl_handler);

        return $this->handleReturn($result, $name, $curl_handler);
    }
}




?>
```

I'm learning programming so i'm in no way good at this.. I need to execute the function `login()` of this class from a url, giving in input the parameters `(private $endpointUrl,private $userName,private $userKey)` and receiving in output the `$sessionId`.

So, for example, i'll write in the url

> https://webserver.com/Login.php? endpointUrl=1&username=2&userKey=3

and receiving in output the `$sessionId`.

Is it possible? How? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible, you have to write your own routes and then do the mapping as PHP frameworks does so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example;

```
if(isset($_GET["endpointUrl"], $_GET["username"], $_GET["userKey"])){
   $x = new Curl_Class($_GET["endpointUrl"], $_GET["username"], $_GET["userKey"]);

   if($x->login()){
      echo $x->token;
   }
}
```

Better if serialize the `GET` input for security purposes. But in this example, just a simple call of login.

Since the `login()` method returning `boolean`, so from there we can know if the `token` created or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So.. i put this just out of the class, and how can i call it from the url?

Comment: I tried in this way: https://test.it/test/Login.php?endpointUrl=https://webserver.it/test&username=admin$userKey=asddasdasqmy3z3qfo but it gives me nothing..

Comment: What do you mean call it from URL? Just create the file in php, and surf the page with the `$_GET` parameters